# Multiple constructor in the base class and call the most suitable one from the derived class in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

I have a base class with two constructors, which accepts `errorMessage` and `errorCode`. `errorMessage` is mandatory but `errorCode` is not.

```
class FooBaseClass{

constructor(errorMessage: String)                   // 1. Constructor
constructor(errorMessage: String, errorCode: Int)   // 2. Constructor

}
```

and a derived class with primary constructor

```
class FooDerivedClass(errorMessage: String, errorCode: Int) :
FooBaseClass(errorMessage, errorCode)
```

I want to design the constructor of my derived class as follows;

if the system provides only `errorMessage`, i want to call the 1.Constructor in the base class. If the system provides both parameters, i want to call the 2.Constructor.

What kind of design solution would suit here as the best solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well you call the overload you need, it's pretty straight forward.

**OPTION 1**

```
class FooBaseClass{
    constructor(errorMessage: String){

    }                   
    constructor(errorMessage: String, errorCode: Int){

    }
}

class FooDerivedClass : FooBaseClass{
     constructor(errorMessage: String) : super(errorMessage)
     constructor(errorMessage: String, errorCode: Int : super(errorMessage, errorCode)
}
```

I would also say if you aren't doing independent things in those constructors it would be easier to use defaults like.

**OPTION 2**

```
class FooBaseClass{                  
    constructor(errorMessage: String, errorCode: Int? = null){
        if(errorCode != null){
            //use it
        }
    }
}

class FooDerivedClass : FooBaseClass{
   constructor(errorMessage: String, errorCode: Int? = null : super(errorMessage, errorCode)
}
```

Just a suggestion. And you can take it one step further, if there is only one constructor you can simply do the default constructor like:

**OPTION 3**

```
class FooBaseClass(errorMessage: String, errorCode: Int? = null){
    val errStr: String = errorMessage
    val errCode: Int? = errorCode        
}

class FooDerivedClass
    constructor(errorMessage: String, errorCode: Int? = null : super(errorMessage, errorCode){

}
```

NOTE* Storing in local variables is only necessary if you are doing get/set databinding, or other annotations that require a variable to add onto.

Happy Coding

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I am not sure if it is the correct way to achieve this because when i define the errorCode: Int? = null like that, the the constructor with two parameters will be called and error code will be set null. I might also include that i cannot change the FooBaseClass because it is from the java standard library.

Comment: Hi Ad, I supplied you with 3 options. so if the Baseclass if fixed, then simply use the first option I supplied. You are not forced to pass the int, it is optional. You will run through the non-int constructor. Please review the first option I gave you.

Comment: The Int? is just if you take my last solution which was assuming you had full control of the base class and is a clean way to manage it. But if you don't have ownership of the base class then you will need two separate constructors as in the first example. Just to be clear

Comment: Thanks Sam for the detailed answer. I think the first option is the best solution in my case :)

Comment: No problem, happy to help. btw, if you are just diving into Kotlin, checkout coroutines experimental. It completely changed the way I code. It's insanely helpful in doing threading and waiting for results from async tasks. A bit of a learning curve, but if you get some time and haven't played with it yet, you should ;).

Comment: well... as we have the [1.3RC](https://blog.jetbrains.com/kotlin/2018/09/kotlin-1-3-rc-is-here-migrate-your-coroutines/), you may even want to jump into that ;-) Then the coroutines wouldn't be experimental anymore (and you wouldn't need to migrate then ;-))

Comment: YAAAASSS I had no idea. Thanks @Roland, that is exciting stuff :). Nerd talk ;)